Is there any UV-mapping related ways to separate UV maps for each finger so I can make them look different?
I'm very new to Blender.
All five fingers shared the same texture file. Is there any UV-mapping related ways to separate UV maps for each finger so I can make them look different?
I've tried searching through the internet and UV map options, but still got no clue.


Hello, do you mean that you want a different color for each finger?

You might need to check some basic UVs videos. When you do UV unwrap you will be able to separate the UVs by parts using seams.
